# How do I prevent socket() system call from returning file descriptor 0,1 or 2?

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am using socketpair() system call for IPC and it returns 0,1 or 2 file descriptor if any of them is available. Using write() system call for fd 0 writes to the STDIN thereby messing up the output of my application. Is there something I can do to prevent the socketpair() from returning 0,1 or 2 as fd ?

Comment: Using `write()` to FD 0 writes to whaever 0 is connected to. If it's a socket, it isn't `stdin`, and it can't 'mess up the output of your application'. It isn't clear that you have a problem to solve.

Comment: The returnvalue from socketpair is **not** a file descriptor, it is a status code (-1 or 0), meaning failure or success.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say that the socket is allocated the file descriptor 0,1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close standard input, standard output or standard error before using `socketpair()`.  If necessary, open `/dev/null` for those file descriptors.

When file descriptors are allocated (by any system call — `open()`, `socket()`, `socketpair()`, `accept()`, `pipe()`, `dup()`, etc), the number used is always the lowest available (unopen) number.  If you're getting 0, 1 or 2 allocated by `socketpair()`, it means you must have closed the corresponding descriptor — but why did you do that?  Never mind; don't do it.

Or fix it by opening `/dev/null`.  Remember that 0 should be readable and 1 and 2 should be writable (and that it doesn't matter if 0 is writable and 1 and 2 are readable; indeed, when a shell is started in a terminal, all three are often readable *and* writable).

Comment: You are right, I was never closing the STD*. The problem was somewhere else.